# Replacing text with data from pg-promise

Tags: node.js, pg-promise

I would like to replace some text in a string with values from a database using `pg-promise`. As I have not used *Promise*s before, I'm struggling with how to deal with it in the best way.

What I have tried so far doesn't work as I try to combine synchronous and asynchronous programming:

```
var uid = ...;
"Some string".replace(/\#\{([\w]*?)\}/gmi, function(m, c) {
    var r = "";
    db.one("SELECT a FROM ... WHERE x = $1 AND y = $2", [c, uid])
        .then(function(data) {
            r = data.a;
        });
    return r;
});
```

`r` is, unsurprisingly, an empty string. Is there a way to rewrite this block to "wait" for the values from the database?

---

What I try to do is, to replace placeholders in a message that is send to the user. So the above is part of a function called `prepareMessage` and I send the message to the user using *socket.io* so it looks something like this:

`io.to(socket.id).emit('message', { text: prepareMessage(msg) });`

Comment: You've got your logic reversed: first, you execute your asynchronous block, and once you get your data, do the synchronous part, and not the other way around.

Comment: @vitaly-t I understand the general idea, but can't really translate it to my problem. Could you provide an example in pseudo-code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading and more thinking, I came up with a solution which I'd like to add if someone else has a similar problem.

(In addition to the question above, I had the additional complication that my message is an array of strings and that the order was to be kept.)

The key was to use [tasks](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#tasks) to send all queries to the DB as one package and wait for all results to return. This led to the following code:

```
// Sample data
var messages = ["String 1 with no placeholder.",
"String 2, #{placeholder1}, String 2.2.",
"String 3 with some more #{placeholder2}."];

// Collect all matches in array
var matches = [];
messages.forEach(function(text, index) {
  const regex = /\#\{([\w]*?)\}/gmi;
  var m;
  do {
    matches.push(regex.exec(text))
  } while(m);
});

// Request data from the database
db.task(function(t) {
  return t.batch(matches.map(function(m) {
    return t.oneOrNone("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id = $1", [m[1]])
  }));
})
.then(function(r) {
        // Replace all occurrences of placeholders
        r.forEach(function(p) {
          messages = messages.map(function(t) { return t.replace("#{"+p.id+"}", p.replacement); });
        });

        // Send message to user
        io.emit('text', messages)M
      })
.catch(function(e) {
        // ... error handling ...
      });
```